# change of parameters, surfaces

Tags: differential-geometry

Hello I have a very simple question of a proof in the book of Docarmo Differential Geometry. In some page of the book , they said that using the proposition 1 , we can deduce that the parametrizations are also diffeomorphism. How can I prove that? I only know that $ x^{-1} y $ it´s diffeomorphism for all parametrizations y. Using this how can I prove that the function  $ x^{-1} $ it´s also differentiable?  Here are the definitions used in Docarmo of parametrization, and the proposition 1.[image: Parametrization Definition used on Docarmo]

[image: Proposition 1 and the Remark]

Answer (score 1):

The inverse function theorem in tandem with the regularity condition tells you that your paramaterization is a local diffeomorphism, and every bijective local diffeomorphism is a diffeomorphism. This is because being a diffeomorphism is a purely local property, and so locally diffeomorphisms and diffeomorphisms are the same thing (obviously), the only difference is the global property of bijectivity.